# Append to list won't keep the last input on program restart?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to learn Python by doing.

Aim of the code below: To form a part of a larger file in which I will be checking if all info i.e. Address, email add, contact person etc is updated in a list (I am not sure whether to use lists, arrays or dictionary?). If yes I want it to give options to do various things for the customer etc.

The code below is basically checking whether a customer exists in the list. If not, it is supposed to add the customer name in `c` to the list.

When I run the program it works. But as soon as I restart the program the last added, i.e. if I entered the customer as: ABC in the last run of the program, is not in the list.

Can someone point me in the right direction on this? Also can I pass the values in the list onto multiple dictionaries as keys for further values to be added i.e. email address etc?

```
customer = ['GMS']
print ("Enter Customer Name:")
c = input()
if c in customer:
    print ("Customer Exsists")

else:
    customer.append(c)
    print ("Added to list")
```

Comment: If you want to keep the data between program executions you have to save the data to file. Check out file operations in python and the `pickle` module.

Comment: Thanks, `pickle` is intimidating for the current time being. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is fine as far as it goes. It does input, and it does
append to the list.

However, all the data in the program will go away as soon as the program
exits. The only way to retain information across runs is to save the
information in some kind of persistent storage. As Rok Novosel mentions
in the comment, this can be done with the `pickle` module, though as a
beginner, you might want to defer that until later.

At this stage of your learning, I’d recommend looking at file
operations: opening and closing, reading and writing. For a single list
like this, the `writelines()` and `readlines()` file methods would be
the simplest way to save and restore, respectively.

As for your dictionary question: yes, since you’re making sure the
customer names are unique, you can use them as dictionary keys. Storing
that data would be more complicated; you could use `pickle`, or work out
a file structure to parse on input.

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Your data resides in `memory` during one execution instance. When the program exits, the `memory` is freed and your data is not automatically stored elsewhere. You may use a format you like to store it onto the `disk` where data is persistent. Simply writing to a file could work for you at this moment of your learning.

Q2: Yes, you may use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Open file and read it in list

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    customers = list(f)
    f.close()
```

Do whatever You want to list. Then write to file.
To persist customers on HDD.

```
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    for l in f:
        f.write(str(l) + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Comment: You needn't call `f.close()` as `with` i.e. context manager will call it automatically.

Comment: Thank You Paul. Changed it.

Comment: No I mean that you can literally remove the call to close. It wont do any harm being there but it will work fine without it.